# The probability that the sum of two exponential random variables is smaller than $2$

Tags: probability, random-variables

The time it takes to service a car is an exponential random variable with rate 1.

If A.J.'s car and M.J.'s car are both brought in at time 0, with work starting on M.J.'s car only when A.J.'s car has been completely serviced, what is the probability that M.J.'s car is ready before time 2?

The answer's $1 - 3e^{-2}$ but I keep getting $1 + e^{-2}$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: _How_ are you getting $1+e^{-2}$?

Comment: $=P(Poisson(2)\ge 2)=1-e^{-2}-2e^{-2}=1-3e^{-2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1,X_2$ be the fixing time random variables following the exponential distribution. The pdf of  the distribution is $f(x) =e^{-x}$ and its cdf is $F(x)=1-e^{-x}$. Observe that if the first car takes time $t\leq 2$ to fix, then the probability of finishing the other car within two hours is exactly $F(2-t)$. By integrating over $t$ we get
$$\Pr[X_1 + X_2\leq 2] =\int_0^2 f(t) F(2-t) \text{d} t = 1-3e^{-2}$$